# Populate an array with the contents of a string object

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, arrays, string

I have a string that gets it contents from a URL. Im trying to put these contents into an array that will populate a table view. Here is the code I have. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.247.245.87/index.php"];

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *nameArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:<#(NSURL *)#>;

    return nameArray.count;

}
```

Comment: How do you wish to populate an array with a string? Is it .csv style, with different elements delimited by a certain character?

Comment: What response do u get..after running the URL in browser??

Comment: @AppleDelegate I get a series of Names separated by commas.

Comment: @Rickay I wish to populate the array with the contents of that string, which is encoded with JSON. The web browser shows the data (names) separated by commas.

Comment: Here is what it looks like in the browser: ["Young, Jason","Fairfield, John","Youngberg, Molly"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are several ways to do this, but here's a simple way to parse JSON results into arrays. Download the SBJSON framework from [here](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)
and add it to your project.  Then import the JSON.h file to your `#import "JSON.h"`.  After which you can parse the string into an array using this line of code `nameArray = [responseString JSONValue];`.

1. Get SBJSON from [here](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/).
2. Add SBJSON to your project and Import JSON.h like so `#import "JSON.h"`
3. Parse to array like so `nameArray = [responseString JSONValue];`

Happy Coding!

EDIT:
you can try do something like this to check to see if you have an array of Strings after you parse the JSON into an array:

> for (NSString* myString in nameArray){
>      NSLog(@"%@",myString);
>     }

if the above works out then you can get the strings from the array and fill the tableview in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate like so:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try it and see where it goes!

Comment: Ok this worked for determining how many rows there will be based on how much data there is. Now I need to show the data in the table rows. I know it has to do with this:
        `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    return cell;
}`

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if you need any additional help.  Just a heads up, if your project has ARC enabled, you may need to add the -"fno-objc-arc" compiler flag for the files from SBJSON framework (there seems to be a stable ARC version though).

Comment: Typically you will get an array of dictionaries, but the JSON structures that I have worked with are a little more complex than the sample your provided. I would suggest just iterating the array and trying to instantiate a NSString object from the content of each index.

Comment: Can you give me an example? What you said went right over my head :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18597/discussion-between-charles-vincent-and-sparq)

Comment: Thanks again for answering the question. It helped me tons!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
return nameArray.count;
```

you will always get 0 because you dont wait for response from serwer.

Comment: When I add this line right above the "return" statement the debug window populates everything immediately.    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Whatever thread this operation is being performed on will simply be suspended until a response is received from the server. If it is done on the main thread, then the thread will be paused.

Comment: I concur with what Rickay said, That said, keep that code as far away from the main thread as you possibly can.

Comment: Definitely. Even better, use NSURLConnection for more control over errors and asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

use this after `NSData`..

```
NSArray *array =   [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

return array;
```

Comment: This answer gives me the following compile warning: "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'NSArray *_strong' from a function with result type 'NSInteger" (aka 'int');